# Best option for connecting MacBook Pro with USB-C to monitor with DisplayPort and HDMI?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hdmi, displayport

I have a Dell U2715H monitor connected to Thunderbolt port on my 2013 MacBook Pro using a Mini DisplayPort cable. With the new MacBook Pro with USB-C port I'm wondering what the best option would be to connect the monitor. It has both DisplayPort and HDMI ports.

If I purchased the [Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) adapter could I then plug the Mini DisplayPort cable into the Thunderbolt 2 end? Would that work?

Alternatively I presume I could get the [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) which contains an HDMI port and then purchase a seperate HDMI cable.

Assuming both solutions would work and ignoring cost is one solution superior?

Comment: I just wrote an answer for a similar question:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259980/119271

Comment: @Allan Great link. That is a little more complicated then here - Joel only needs one display which should work quite easily. The other is asking if Apple's limitation of two external displays can be ignored.

Comment: @joel72 I have the exact same monitor and requirement, can you state what you eventually went for?

Comment: I've just tried an HDMI/HDMI cable with the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter on my Dell U2414H, and the display wouldn't pick up the signal from the MBP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go for USB-C to DisplayPort directly. That would be one relatively inexpensive ($20 to $40 US prices) cable to do the job. Since your display won't charge the MacBook and do video over a single USB-C cable and you have several ports (display side and Mac side) - a dedicated cable would be my choice.

I like the USB-C to HDMI adapter you mentioned for my MacBook since there is only one port and charging plus USB is needed, but on the MacBook Pro you have several ports and can use one per display without too much hassle. It will work for you, though - just not my first choice.

Apple even recommends against using the adapter you mention for bridging between a Mini DisplayPort device and thunderbolt 3. 
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154

> Note that although it uses a Mini DisplayPort connector, the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter doesn't support connections to Mini DisplayPort displays.

If you only want two external displays, both 13 inch models of MacBook Pro are suitable. You'll need the 15 inch models to support 4 displays. That might be a non-issue if you only have one Dell display to connect.

Comment: Do you mean the Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter with a mini-DP cable attached to the Thunderbolt 2 end? If not, I can't see any Apple adapters that do USB-C to mini-DP.

Comment: @Joel72 not apple - third party. Try "usb c displayport" on Amazon or similar. Apple never made a full DisplayPort anything. Cable Matters and other vendors make some decent to good quality cables in my experience. It will be interesting to see if that Dell can charge your new MacBook with a cable.

Comment: which usb-c to display port is the best quality?